# XRPL signing transaction, stuck at getting xrpl wallet from secret numbers

Tags: node.js, ripple, xrp

I have 6 digits 8 rows secret numbers.
How to convert/use my secret numbers with xrpl.Wallet.fromMnemonic or xrpl.Wallet.fromSecret method?

```
const xrpl = require("xrpl")
const PUBLIC_SERVER = "wss://xrplcluster.com/"
const client = new xrpl.Client(PUBLIC_SERVER)
await client.connect()
const wallet = xrpl.Wallet.fromMnemonic('A:112121 B:222222 C:333333 D:444444 E:555555 F:656565 G:156545 H:454545')
console.log(wallet) 
......
```

Answer (score 0):

xrpl.js doesn't support XUMM-style "secret numbers" at the moment. If you want to use your secret numbers with xrpl.js you need to [convert them to family seed format](https://support.xumm.app/hc/en-us/articles/360018136180-Using-a-XUMM-XRPL-account-Secret-Numbers-in-another-XRPL-client).